# Convergence in measure and convergence of norm implies convergence in L^p

Tags: analysis

I have been attacking this question but i got stuck. Please give me some hint.

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $\{f_n\}\subset L^p$. Suppose $f_n\to f$ in measure and $\|f_n\|_p\to\|f\|_p$, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ norm.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy. The key idea is to mimic the proof of Dominated Convergence Theorem. In order to do that, first establish the following inequality:
$$\lvert x+y\rvert^p\le\gamma_p(\lvert x\rvert^p+\lvert y\rvert)^p,\qquad\forall x,y\in\mathbb C$$
for some constant $\gamma_p$. Then apply [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma#Convergence_in_measure) to $g_n=\gamma_p(\lvert f_n\rvert^p+\lvert f\rvert^p)-\lvert f_n-f\rvert^p$, which shows that $\limsup_n\int\lvert f_n-f\rvert^p\le0$.

For a reference, see Walter Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, Exercise 3.17.